# Move/Shift a line toward x and y axises in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a function in SQL Server to move/shift a geometry toward X or Y axises?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implement STShidt function myself and use [SQL Server CLR Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx) to deploy it to SQL server.

STShift implementation is:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlGeometry STShift(SqlGeometry g, double xShift, double yShift)
{
    var sqlGeometryBuilder = new SqlGeometryBuilder();
    var shiftGeometrySink = new ShiftGeometrySink(xShift, yShift, sqlGeometryBuilder);
    g.Populate(shiftGeometrySink);
    return sqlGeometryBuilder.ConstructedGeometry;
}
```

and ShiftGeometrySink is an implementation of IGeometrySink110 interface:

```
 public class ShiftGeometrySink : IGeometrySink110
    {
        private readonly IGeometrySink110 _target;
        private readonly double _xShift;
        private readonly double _yShift;

        public ShiftGeometrySink(double xShift, double yShift, IGeometrySink110 target)
        {
            _target = target;
            _xShift = xShift;
            _yShift = yShift;
        }

        public void SetSrid(int srid)
        {
            _target.SetSrid(srid);
        }

        public void BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType type)
        {
            _target.BeginGeometry(type);
        }

        public void BeginFigure(double x, double y, double? z, double? m)
        {
            _target.BeginFigure(x + _xShift, y + _yShift, z, m);
        }

        public void AddLine(double x, double y, double? z, double? m)
        {
            _target.AddLine(x + _xShift, y + _yShift, z, m);
        }

        public void EndFigure()
        {
            _target.EndFigure();
        }

        public void EndGeometry()
        {
            _target.EndGeometry();
        }

        public void AddCircularArc(double x1, double y1, double? z1, double? m1, double x2, double y2, double? z2, double? m2)
        {
           _target.AddCircularArc(x1, y1, z1, m1, x2, y2, z2, m2);
        }
    }
```